# Calculate elapsed time

Tags: python, datetime

I have a text file that always looks like this:

```
977-183 BCA-0055 2014-02-19 10:08:13.61
977-001 BCA-0058 2014-02-19 10:29:08.18
977-013 BCA-0064 2014-02-19 10:28:35.73
977-129 BCA-0079 2014-02-19 10:15:45.24
```

These are generators. My goal is to add an additional column showing the total hours they have been running until now, which is when the I run the script. I am brand new to python and am stuck. I have figured out how to make a datetime object? for the now time. I had hoped to use this in my calculations (timedelta?) but have not been able to create a datetime for the times in the text file to move on.
I have tried some things and read quite a bit but no luck, here is code showing my latest attempt:

```
import datetime
import time

i = datetime.datetime.now()
print i

# this is what the raw data looks like
# 977-183 BCA-0055 2014-02-19 10:08:13.61

raw0 = open("genParse.txt", "r") # text file containing date and time
fin0 = open("elapsed_time.txt", "w") # will contain elapsed times

for line in raw0:
    if '977-' in line:
       line = line.split() 
       date = line[2]
       time = line[3]
             # create datetime object for use in elapsed time calculations
             #tnew = datetime.datetime(date[0:4], date[5:7], date[8:10])
             print date[0:4], date[5:7], date[8:10]
```

Comment: I do not quite understand. Do you want to show the difference between now() and the timestamp in your text file entries?

Comment: What kind of output for the elapsed time were you looking for?

Comment: note: local time may be ambiguous and non-monotonous. Use UTC timezone if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse your strings to `datetime.datetime()` objects:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date + ' ' + time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Now you can calculate the time elapsed:

```
elapsed = now - dt
```

which is a `timedelta` object.

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> date = '2014-02-19'
>>> time = '10:08:13.61'
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date + ' ' + time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 19, 10, 8, 13, 610000)
>>> now - dt
datetime.timedelta(6, 30419, 490913)
```

The resulting `timedelta` object here has a value of 6 days, 30419 seconds and 490913 microseconds. How you format that to a string is up to you.

Comment: File "elapsed_time.py", line 29
  dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date + ' ' + time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f)  Tried using  `time2 = time[0:11]` in place of time but same error

Comment: @Cellular777: Comments do not handle newlines. Do you have input that doesn't match your sample?

Comment: @Cellular777: You didn't give me the exception. What is the exact value of `date` and `time` at the time of the exception?

Comment: Sorry, first question ever! Here is the rest of error message: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: I am using the sample as input

Comment: @Cellular777: Then you made an error in your version of the code; by the looks of it you didn't close the string (a quote is missing at the end of the time parse format).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the difference between the entry and when the script is executed:

```
from datetime import datetime

raw0 = open("genParse.txt", "r") # text file containing date and time
fin0 = open("elapsed_time.txt", "w") # will contain elapsed times

for line in raw0:
    if '977-' in line:
        line = line.split() 
        dts = '%s %s' % (line[2], line[3])
        now = datatime.now()
        fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
        time_diff = datetime.strptime(now, FMT) - datetime.strptime(dts, FMT)
```

You can obviously do whatever you want with `time_diff`, which is a `timedelta` object. Print, to file, etc. This is just expanding on the code you have already written. Like always with Python, there are many ways to accomplish the same goal.

Comment: Your format won't handle the 100s of seconds value: `ValueError: unconverted data remains: .61`.